# PHP updating multiple rows using class method

Tags: php, mysql

i have a class method inserMultiplerecords, im trying to convert it to work for updating multiple records too. is this possible?

```
public function insertMultiple($tableName, $data){
    //Will contain SQL snippets.
    $rowsSQL = array();

    //Will contain the values that we need to bind.
    $toBind = array();

    //Get a list of column names to use in the SQL statement.
    $columnNames = array_keys($data[0]);

    //Loop through our $data array.
    foreach($data as $arrayIndex => $row){
        $params = array();
        foreach($row as $columnName => $columnValue){
            $param = ":" . $columnName . $arrayIndex;
            $params[] = $param;
            $toBind[$param] = $columnValue; 
        }
        $rowsSQL[] = "(" . implode(", ", $params) . ")";
    }

    //Construct our SQL statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` (" . implode(", ", $columnNames) . ") VALUES " . implode(", ", $rowsSQL);

    //Prepare our PDO statement.
    $pdoStatement = $this->prepare($sql);

    //Bind our values.
    foreach($toBind as $param => $val){
        $pdoStatement->bindValue($param, $val);
    }
    //Execute our statement (i.e. insert the data).
    return $pdoStatement->execute();
}
```

can anybody help me to convert it to work into updating record?? thanks in advance

Comment: So what have you tried? You just cant give us some code and then ask us to change it do to something else. Especially when you haven't shown that you have even researched on how you would do this... Do you know how to perform an Update?

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"